# How to generate multiple pages from Swashbuckle.AspNet?

Tags: asp.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I've been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?tabs=visual-studio) to create developer friendly documentation for my ASP.Net REST WebApi using Swashbuckle.
However, the current version `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v2.2.0` generates a huge single page app, which is confusing for my users.
If I remember correctly, Swashbuckle was generating separate pages for each controller/method (early 2017?). My configuration looks like this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
    c.EnableFilter();
    c.MaxDisplayedTags(5);
});
```

**Q:** Is there any way to make Swagger-UI generate separate pages for each controller and method instead of a huge single scrolling mess?

Some more Details:

- VS2017
- Microsoft.AspNetCore 2.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 2.2.0
- Pure WebApi - only JSON is generated, no HTML at all.
- Self Hosting via Kestrel on

  - either Windows using net 4.6.2 (here Swashbuckle is used)
  - or embedded Linux using dotnet core 2.0 (Swashbuckle disabled)

Answer (score 8):

Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v2.2.0 has support of arbitrary grouping of API actions into multiple Swagger documents.

Please refer the documentation here:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#generate-multiple-swagger-documents

Comment: Unfortunatley, those documents are not linked. Usually, this features is used for versioning or to differentiate independent services. I'm looking for page/sub/sub pattern instead of SPA.

Comment: I believe that there is no direct support in Swashbuckle, to implement the functionality the way you want. 
What you can do is to write your  post-processing step that takes the full Swagger description and splits into multiple files based on the value found in each the tags attribute for each Operation as mentioned here : https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/764